Check if string does not contain strings from the list with wildcard when % symbol in the list value
newlist = ['test', '%ing', 'osh', '16fg']
tartext = 'Singing'

I want to check my tartext value doesn't matching with any value with newlist. if the newlist string contains % symbol in the value then I need to match this as wildcard charecter.
I want to achieve condition as below.
if (tartext != 'test' and tartext not like '%ing' and tartext != 'osh' and tartext != 
'16fg') then return true else false

Since %ing from the lsit contains '%' symbol in it I need to change the comparison as wildcard chatecter search like sql.
In this example 'Singing' is matching with '%ing' then I am expecting the condition to return False.
Below is the code that I have tried but didn't work
import re

newlist = ['test', '%ing', 'osh', '16fg']
tartext = 'Singing'

def wildcard_compare(string, match):
    match = match.replace('%','.*')#.replace('_','.')
    match_expression = f'^{match}$'
    return bool(re.fullmatch(match_expression,string))


def condition_match(lookupstring, mylist):
    for value in mylist:
        if '%' in value:
            if not wildcard_compare(lookupstring,value):
                return True
        else:
            if value != lookupstring:
                return True
    return False

print(condition_match(tartext,newlist))
print(condition_match('BO_IN',['AP_IN','BO_IN','CA_PS']))


Python already supports wildcard-matching via the fnmatch module, so there's no need to reinvent the wheel (unless you really must use % instead of *).

One approach would be to use regular expressions.  In this approach, we can replace % in the newlist by .*.  Then, use re.search along with a list comprehension to find any matches.
newlist = ['test', '%ing', 'osh', '16fg']
tartext = 'Singing'

newlist = [r'^' + x.replace('%', '.*') + r'$' for x in newlist]
num_matches = sum([1 for x in newlist if re.search(x, tartext)])

if num_matches > 0:
    print("found a match")  # prints here
else:
    print("no matches")

Edit:
See the comment below by @ekhumoro in the case that your input string might also have regex metacharacters in it.

re.search seems to be in appropriate. if my newlist = ['test', '%ing', 'osh', '16fg'] tartext = 'tests'. It still return "found a match" :(

@RoshanN I edited my answer to place ^ and $ anchors around the pattern.

Isn't this the task for fullmatch rather than search with anchors?

This will fail if newlist includes strings containing regex special characters. Also, it is unnecessarily inefficient, because it creates all the patterns up front and doesn't stop on the first match. It would be better to use any with a generator expression, which can be reduced to a one-liner: any(re.fullmatch(re.escape(ptn).replace('%', '.*'), tartext) for ptn in newlist).

@ekhumoro Agree with your comment.  I posted my answer as a concept answer more than anything else.
